# probability that exactly two digits repeat twice in a 6 digit number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have a random number with digits from 0-9. The size of the random number is 6 digits and we have to find out the probability that exactly two digits repeat twice in the random number. Example would be 001134.

Comment: The practice of merely posing a problem with an apparent expectation that Readers will provide a solution is discouraged.  If you are motivated to learn mathematics, you will have attempted to solve the problem yourself before posting.  Your research and attempts will then give context to the Question that expedites helping you learn *how* to approach the problem with reasoned mathematical arguments.

Comment: I keep getting negative marks.  . but I give up fighting against big brother.----You can use a multinomial distribution.  The typical term is $\frac{6!}{n_0!n_1!...n_9!}$ with all $n_k\ge 0$ and $\sum n_k=6$.  Collect terms with two $n_k=2$.and not three $n_k=2$.  sum and divide by $10^6$.Calculation:  for any pair of digits there are $\frac{6!}{2!2!}=180$ possibilities.  There are $45$ pairs of double digits and 28 pairs of single digits so that the total number of possibilities $=226800$ resulting in a probability of $0.2268$.

Note $45=\frac{10\times 9}{2}$ and $28=\frac{8\times 7}{2}$.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to find the number of possible numbers and divide the result by $900\,000$ to get your probability. Or $1\,000\,000$ if you are letting leading zeros.

The second case is not hard. First, choose two numbers to be the repeated ones. You can do this in $10C2=45$ ways. Then, pick $2$ positions for the first pair and $2$ positions for the lower pair. This can be done in $6C2*4C2=90$ ways. Finally, choose two more numbers. You can do this in $8C2=28$ ways. Then, you have $2$ ways to order them in the remaining slots.

Therefore, you have $45*90*28*2=226800$ different numbers that work in this interpretation. This is a $\displaystyle \frac{226800}{1000000}=\frac{567}{2500}$

Answer (score 0):

There are $10^{6}$ numbers total.

The ones that have the right property can also be counted: pick the first repeating digit (10 ways) and pick the two positions out of 6 it can be, in $\binom{6}{2}$ ways. Then pick a new digit ($9$ ways) and pick two new positions in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways. (note that we can pick these two digits in two orders, in your example I could have started by $0$ or by $1$ and gotten the same result, so we overcount by a factor of $2$, which we divide by later) and finally $8$ (for the leftmost of the positions left) and $7$ for the last one.

So I get $\frac{10 \times 9 \times \binom{6}{2}\times \binom{4}{2} \times \frac12 \times 8 \times 7}{10^{6}}= \frac{2268}{10000}$ in all.

Comment: In your numerator, why is there a $\times 2$ in the middle of $8\times 2\times 7$?

Comment: @JMoravitz and times $\frac12$ really, too for the same overcounting reason.

Comment: @herbsteinberg it's the same as Saketh's